# Sum in Ruby array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to do a program that asks the user for three numbers one at a time, store them in array, then print the list of the numbers and the total.

Please explain.

Here is what I have so far:

```
numbers = Array.new
numbers = []
puts "Enter first number: "
first = gets.to_i
puts "Enter second number: "
second = gets.to_i
puts "Enter third number: "
third = gets.to_i
def sum(numbers)
  return 0 if numbers.length < 1
  result = 0
  numbers.each { |num| result += num }
  result
end
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to add them to the array as well?

Comment: why are you making two `numbers` arrays, which are identical?

Comment: I'm new on ruby so I'm not sure what I'm doing

Comment: For the sum, just use numbers.sum If there might be nils, use numbers.compact.sum

Comment: @DavidAldridge `#sum` method is available only via ActiveSupport. It isn't present in Plain Ol' Ruby.

Comment: Oh right. Seems like an oversight ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use Array's reduce method.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
numbers = Array.new
# numbers = [] #this is same as above
puts "Enter first number: "
first = gets.to_i
numbers<<first
puts "Enter second number: "
second = gets.to_i
numbers<<second
puts "Enter third number: "
third = gets.to_i
numbers<<third
puts numbers.reduce {|sum, n| sum + n } #here
```

Comment: There's no need to define temporary variables `first`, `second` and `third`; just write `numbers << gets.to_i` three times. Also, you can calculate the sum as `numbers.reduce(:+)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you can even use `3.times.map { gets.to_i }.reduce(:+)` as  `times` returns `Enumerator` if there is no block given.

Comment: @Hauleth, almost. See Wand's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more way of doing this:

```
sum = 3.times.collect{ |i| puts "Enter number #{i + 1}:"; gets.chomp.to_i }.inject(:+)
puts sum
```

Could also be written like below:

```
read_num = lambda{|i| puts "Enter number #{i}"; gets.chomp.to_i}
sum = 3.times.map(&read_num).reduce(:+)
puts sum
```

Comment: ..or `%w|first second third|.collect { |w| puts "Enter #{w} number";...`. I suggest you reformat to avoid the need for horizontal scrolling.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - Yeah that's one possibility - thought it may be good idea to have flexibility of doing `N.times`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't pushed any of your inputs into the array, you can either use the push function or the << to add elements to your array

```
  #!/usr/bin/ruby
numbers = Array.new
numbers = []
puts "Enter first number: "
first = gets.to_i
numbers<<first
puts "Enter second number: "
second = gets.to_i
numbers<<second
puts "Enter third number: "
third = gets.to_i
numbers<<first
def sum(someArray)
  return 0 if someArray.length < 1
  result = 0
  someArray.each { |num| result += num }
  result
end
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here:

1. You aren't pushing the numbers you read into the array
2. You defined the `sum` function properly, but aren't calling it anywhere

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
numbers = Array.new # note the second, redundant, initialization on numbers was removed
puts "Enter first number: "
(numbers ||= []) << gets.to_i # Pushing read value into the array (issue 1)
puts "Enter second number: "
(numbers ||= []) << gets.to_i # Here too
puts "Enter third number: "
(numbers ||= []) << gets.to_i # And here too
def sum(numbers)
  return 0 if numbers.length < 1
  result = 0
  numbers.each { |num| result += num }
  result
end

puts sum(numbers) # Calling sum (issue 2)
```

Comment: Considering that you've already initialized `numbers` to be an empty array, why `(numbers ||= []) << gets.to_i` rather than simply `numbers << gets.to_i`? Also, one normally uses `Hash#reduce` to calculate simple sums.

Comment: I don't get need for `||=` either.